# Associative arrays in different encodings in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associate

I have a set of property names, and its possible values, taken from database.I want to perform some array manipulation, so I get all possible values of the property in an array.

So the code would be something like:

```
$associative_array[$row->PropertyName][] = $row->value;
```

The problem is that I am not too confident that this may work in other encodings rather than the default, and I have problems with `sort` to start with, having to set the **locale**.

Is it a good approach or should I have something like this:

```
  $properties_array[ $row->PropertyId][] = $row->value;
```

where I am using the numeric and unique PropertyId, and I will take the properyName in another way, for example, like this:

```
  $properties_array[ $row->PropertyId][] = array($row->PropertyName, $row->value);
```

Comment: If you use PHP7 you will not have any probs with encoding :)

Comment: Well, I am still using PHP5. Somehow I don't feel comfortable with a language where you can only use `function_name` ( $parameter )[ index ] in one of its latest 5.x versions and before that it will throw an error. I will take your comment as a vote por the second approach in my question.

Comment: I guess you can try to "guess" the current encoding of PropertyId and encode it into UTF-8 or something... See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: Yes, though you may refer to PropertyName. It is a good idea. In any case, I think I am choosing the second solution because the first one is not trusty, though to be honest I have found no problems, except for `sort` and the like.

Comment: The best way is still to have a single encoding in database :D But you are right, this way you will not have to maintain a tricky code ;)